# Can I reset my Google Cloud Platform account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Long story short, my Google Cloud Platform account is bugged out. Can I "factory reset" my GCP account?

Comment: Delete the project and create a new one. You will lose all resources in the project. AFAIK there is no Google supported tool to reset your project.

Comment: What do you mean by "bugged out" ? Can you provide more details ?

Comment: @W_B Unknown Error at various places

Comment: Do you maybe have (or can create) another project that you can check if you're getting the same errors ?

Comment: @W_B It was the organization with the problem. I ended up just using a completely different domain/organization.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Cloud console, go to the Manage resources page. In the project list, select the project that you want to delete, and then click Delete.

Then you can create a new project.